# php simplexml with dot character in element in xml

Tags: php, simplexml

With the below xml format how we can access News.Env element from XMLReader in php?

`$xmlobj->News->News.Env` gives Env which is not correct.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<News>
  <News.Env>abc</News.Env>
</News>
```

Comment: You're sure that you're talking about `XMLReader`? That syntax looks more like `SimpleXML`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is because the dot `.` is the string concatenator in php. In your case it tries to concatenate `$xmlobj->News->News` (which doesn't exists and is therefore empty) with the constant `Env` (which doesn't exists too and is treated as a string. you would get a notice about this with an appropriate error_level)

```
$tmp = 'News.Env';
$xmlobj->News->$tmp;
```

or in short

```
$xmlobj->News->{'News.Env'};
```

Update: If you use `SimpleXML` (and according the syntax you do it) it `$xmlobj` "starts" with the `News`-(root-)Element.

```
$xmlobj->{'News.Env'};
```

Comment: If `$xmlobj` is a `SimpleXMLElement` (and not an `XMLReader`), the correct syntax will be `$xmlobj->{'News.Env'}` because `$xmlobj` already represents the root `<News>`-node.

Comment: Yes, just realized myself. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Another issue what if element starting from @.     {@attributes} not working :(

Comment: As far as I remember XML-elements _cannot_ start with `@`.

Comment: got it... showing attribute like parameter in simplexml... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<News>
    <News.Env>abc</News.Env>
</News>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($xml->{'News.Env'});
```