# SimpleXML: How to parse nodenames including dots with xpath query

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have to parse the following XML:

```
<BMECAT version="2005" xmlns="http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/2005fd">
    <T_NEW_CATALOG prev_version="0">
        <PRODUCT>
            <NAME>Test</NAME>
            <USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS>
                <UDX.VENDOR.ATTRIBUTE lang="de">German</UDX.VENDOR.ATTRIBUTE>
                <UDX.VENDOR.ATTRIBUTE lang="en">English</UDX.VENDOR.ATTRIBUTE>
            </USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS>
        </PRODUCT>
    </T_NEW_CATALOG>
</BMECAT>
```

I need to get the value "German" via xpath. Everything I have tried so far didn't work so I need some help. I think the problem is that the tagname includes dots. I have found no way to escape the xpath expression.

Comment: have you tried proposed workarounds here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531380/php-simplexml-with-dot-character-in-element-in-xml ?

Comment: Can you show some of the xpath queries you tried with the results?

Comment: @jazZRo Well, obviously an expression with `.` in it. In my opinion, the problem is clear already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML you show cannot be parsed because it is malformed (`USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS` is not closed properly). Assuming well-formed input, you could use DOMDocument instead of SimpleXML:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<'XML'
<BMECAT version="2005" xmlns="http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/2005fd">
    <T_NEW_CATALOG prev_version="0">
        <PRODUCT>
            <NAME>Test</NAME>
            <USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS>
                <UDX.VENDOR.ATTRIBUTE lang="de">German</UDX.VENDOR.ATTRIBUTE>
                <UDX.VENDOR.ATTRIBUTE lang="en">English</UDX.VENDOR.ATTRIBUTE>
            </USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS>
        </PRODUCT>
    </T_NEW_CATALOG>
</BMECAT>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace("bme",
        "http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/2005fd");

$expression = 'string(
  /bme:BMECAT
  /bme:T_NEW_CATALOG
  /bme:PRODUCT
  /bme:USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS
  /bme:UDX.VENDOR.ATTRIBUTE[@lang = "de"]
)';

var_dump($xpath->evaluate($expression));
```

And the result will be

```
German
```

If you need to use SimpleXML, you really need to show your current PHP code.

Comment: Sorry, the missing close tag was just a copy & paste error. Thanks for your idea of using DOMDocument. I will give it a try and perhaps use it instead of SimpleXML. Thanks!

Comment: You can fetch the text content directly with: `$xpath->evaluate("string(/bme:BMECAT/bme:T_NEW_CATALOG/bme:PRODUCT/bme:USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS/bme:UDX.VENDOR.ATTRIBUTE[@lang = 'de'])";` No need for the loop :-)

Comment: @ThW Thanks Thomas! I'm not well-versed in PHP as you can see ;).

Comment: Here seems to be some special character hidden in `USER_DEF‌​INED_EXTENSIONS` (a unicode whitespace?). I rewrote it an it works: https://eval.in/260357

Comment: @ThW Yes, meanwhile, I found out myself. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for your code! I have successfully adopted it into my XMLReader. I use a combination of XMLReader and DOMDocument because I have to handle with really large files.